# Kotlin onMethodCall Reply already submitted problem

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I made such a plugin, the codes are as follows

```
package com.powermanager.powermanager

import android.content.Context
import android.os.PowerManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result


/** PowermanagerPlugin */
class PowermanagerPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private lateinit var applicationContext: Context
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private lateinit var powerManager: PowerManager
  private lateinit var lock: PowerManager.WakeLock

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    applicationContext = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "powermanager")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    powerManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    if(powerManager.isWakeLockLevelSupported(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK)) {
      lock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK,"PROXIMITYSCREENOFFWAKELOCK")
      lock.setReferenceCounted(false)
    }
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "on") {
      if(powerManager.isWakeLockLevelSupported(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK)) {
        if(lock.isHeld) {
          lock.release(1)
        }
        lock.acquire()
        result.success(true)
      } else {
        result.error("notSupported", "PowerManager PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK is notSupported", null)
      }
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
    if (call.method == "off") {
      if(powerManager.isWakeLockLevelSupported(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK)) {
        if(lock.isHeld) {
          lock.release(1)
        }
        result.success(true)
      } else {
        result.error("notSupported", "PowerManager PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK is notSupported", null)
      }
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    if(::lock.isInitialized) {
      if(lock.isHeld) {
        lock.release(1)
      }
    }
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

This is how I call

```
_powerManager(bool makeActive) async {
      try {
        if (makeActive) {
          await Powermanager().on();
        } else {
          await Powermanager().off();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _powerManager(true);
  }
@override
  void dispose() {
    _powerManager(false);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

It gives me this error how do I solve it I tried many things but it didn't work, Even if I do it without result, it's not very important to get the value it gives

```
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:435)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.notImplemented(MethodChannel.java:273)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at com.powermanager.powermanager.PowermanagerPlugin.onMethodCall(PowermanagerPlugin.kt:55)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#powermanager(16953):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid to call more than a single `result` method, exactly once, per method call. You are calling it once with an actual reply and once with an incorrect `notImplemented` every time.

You need either one if/else-if/else chain, or a switch, not several unrelated if/else which each always call `result`.